# Implementing Server

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm an iOS developer with experience in C/Obj-C and Swift. I currently finished a weather app that displays current and forecasted weather, with the ability to alert you when certain weather conditions change. This is done using the background fetch feature in iOS, which periodically refreshes weather data in the background to see if your criteria has been met, then sends you a local notification.

Problem: the background fetch only happens at the command of the OS. You have no control and I'd like to be able to check more often to alert customers sooner when the weather is changing. I'm fully aware that the solution is implementing my own server with a program that checks remotely say every minute, then sends a push notification to the customers phone.

My current implementation on the iPhone is:

1. User creates alert with custom criteria (example: tell me when the wind at city X goes above 10mph)
2. App downloads weather from web XML api
3. App parses weather data into custom weather objects
4. App compares weather data to users custom alert
5. App alerts user if criteria was met

What I want to do:

- Send the alert that the user created to a server and store it
- Have the server do all the work of downloading/analyzing if the criteria was met  for each stored alert
- Send a push notification to the users who had criteria met

Question 1: What would this overall implementation on a server look like?

Question 2: What language would each part of the implementation be written in? Currently I have everything working in Swift but I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that won't work on a Linux server

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could store your criteria on the client and use a web API to fetch the weather. This could eliminate your dependency on the OS and give you time to study up on building a server.